# How can I make a URL navigation active in PHP when the variable is empty?

Tags: php, isset

I have a problem to make a url form navigation active so it light up.

I have this code, but it is not working. It has been a while that I used php and it does not accept anymore if the variable is empty.
Can someone help me?
This is the code:

```
<?php
$current1 = ""; $current2 = "";
if (isset($_GET['mode'])) 
//mode not empty
{ 
  $mode = $_GET[ 'mode'];
  echo $mode."<br>";
    if ($mode = "index") { $current1 = "active";$current2="";}
    elseif ($mode = "contact") { $current2 = "active";$current1="";}
}
else 
//mode empty
{ 
 $current1 = "active";$current2="";      
}   
?>
```

Comment: Remember equality tests are done with double equals `==`, otherwise PHP treats it as an assignment.  So your code `if ($mode = "index")` will always evaluate to true, because this is assigning the value "index" to the `$mode` variable.

Comment: Is your navigation only ever going to have two options? What does this code provide for the actual navigation? There might be a smarter way to do this if you provided more context.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser, but I found a simple solution
I just put this where "active" should be in the a href.
<?php if(!isset($_GET['mode']) OR $_GET['mode']=="home"){ echo "active";} ?>

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this might be a simpler way:

```
// default
$current1 = 'active';
$current2 = '';

if (!empty($_GET['mode']) && ($_GET['mode'] == 'contact')) {
    $current1 = '';
    $current2 = 'active';
}
```

Comment: Thanks all for your advice, but I found a simple solution

Answer (score 0):

Isset determine if a variable is declared and is different than null

let's check the [official php example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

```php
$var = '';

// This will evaluate to TRUE so the text will be printed.
if (isset($var)) {
    echo "This var is set so I will print.";
}
```

So you may use empty to check if the $_GET['mode'] is a empty value or no, And for your answer you may code this way:

```php
$modes = [
     'index' => '',
     'contact' => '',
];

$mode = (isset($_GET['mode']) and !empty($_GET['mode'])) ? $_GET['mode'] : 'index';
$modes[$mode] = 'active';

// in case you need your variable:
$current1 = $modes['index'];
$current2 = $modes['contact'];
```

Comment: Thank you for your anwser, but I found a simple solution
I just put this where "active" should be in the a href.
<?php if(!isset($_GET['mode']) OR $_GET['mode']=="home"){ echo "active";} ?>

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple of issues with your code that are preventing it from working correctly. Let's go through them and provide the corrected code:

- Comparison Operator: In your if statements, you are using the assignment operator = instead of the comparison operator == or ===. To compare values, you need to use == for loose comparison or === for strict comparison.
- Multiple Conditions: When comparing multiple conditions within an if statement, you should use the logical operators && (AND) or || (OR) to combine the conditions.
- Variable Assignment: The assignment of the active class is reversed in your code. You have assigned it to $current1 when the mode is "index" and to $current2 when the mode is "contact". It should be the other way around.

Here's the corrected code:

```
$current1 = "";
$current2 = "";

if (isset($_GET['mode'])) {
  $mode = $_GET['mode'];
  echo $mode . "<br>";
  
  if ($mode === "index") {
    $current1 = "active";
    $current2 = "";
  } elseif ($mode === "contact") {
    $current1 = "";
    $current2 = "active";
  }
} else {
  $current1 = "active";
  $current2 = "";
}
```

In this updated code, we use the === operator for strict comparison. We assign the active class to $current1 when the mode is "index" and to $current2 when the mode is "contact". The conditions are now properly separated using the logical operators.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser, but I found a simple solution
I just put this where "active" should be in the a href.
<?php if(!isset($_GET['mode']) OR $_GET['mode']=="home"){ echo "active";} ?>